# Using helpers with the same name but with different parameters

Tags: html, razor, helper, webmatrix

I have two helpers in my page **Project.cshtml**. Here is the code:

```
@helper Fields()
{
    @* How to call a helper Fields(-1)?  *@
}

@helper Fields(int projectID)
{
  @* Code *@
}
```

Can I call a helper in another helper??

Answer (score 3):

I would use [optional arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) instead of providing a number of method overloads:

```
@helper Fields(int projectId = 0){
    if(projectId > 0){
        ....
    }
    ....
}
```